# How to mock @ngrx/store state in Angular 4 unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am developing an Angular 4 application using @ngrx/store and @ngrx/effect, and I am trying to write some unit tests for my effects.

One of my effects is supposed to use a service to get some data from a backend. Once the value is retrieved from the backend, then this effect should be triggered every once in a while to generate a polling effect and update the local data.

Since the polling interval is configured on my application's state, I would like to be able to mock the state store so that I can change it during the tests.

Here is my SPEC:

```js
describe('Order Effects', () => {

  let actions: Observable<any>;
  let effects: OrderEffect;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({ orders: ordersReducer })
      ],
      providers: [
        OrderEffect,
        provideMockActions(() => actions),
        { provide: OrderService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('orderService', ['getAllOrders']) }
      ]
    });

    effects = TestBed.get(OrderEffect);
  });


  it('should load orders and call load orders complete action', () => {

    const mockData = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

    const orderService = TestBed.get(OrderService);
    orderService.getAllOrders.and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockData));

    actions = hot('--a-', { a: new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersAction(new Date()) });

    const expectedEffect = cold('--b|', { b: new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersCompleteAction(mockData) });
    expect(effects.loadAllOrders$).toBeObservable(expectedEffect);
  });

});
```

And here is the effect:

```js
@Injectable()
export class OrderEffect {

  @Effect()
  loadAllOrders$: Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType(orderActions.LOAD_ALL_ORDERS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$) // Get the latest state from the store and add as the second value of the array below
    .switchMap((input: any[]) => {
      const action: orderActions.LoadAllOrdersAction = input[0];
      const store: AppState = input[1];

      return Observable.timer(0, store.orders.pollingInterval) // Timer to create the polling effect.
        .switchMap(() => this.orderService.getAllOrders(action.payload)
          .map((orders: Array<any>) => new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersCompleteAction(orders))
          .catch(error => Observable.throw(new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersFailAction(error)))
        );
    });

  constructor(private actions: Actions, private orderService: OrderService, private store$: Store<AppState>) { }
}
```

In the effect code, I get the current state by using: `.withLatestFrom(this.store$)` and I want to mock this property: `store.orders.pollingInterval`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to get the store state in an effect you must spy on the store when testing this effect so you could mock its state.

```js
describe('Order Effects', () => {
    // ...
    let ordersStateMock = {
        orders: {
            pollingInterval: null
        }
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        const storeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('storeSpy', [
            'dispatch', 'subscribe'
        ]);
        storeSpy.select = () => Observable.of(ordersStateMock);
        // ...
    });
});
```

Then in your state you could set the value you want for the store state :

```js
it('should load orders and call load orders complete action', () => {
    // ...
    ordersStateMock.orders.pollingInterval = 2;
    actions = hot('--a-', { a: new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersAction(new Date()) });
    // ...
});
```

I use this solution in my tests. I got it in the book 'Reactive Programming with Angular and ngrx'. It refers to ngrx and Angular v2 but it still is very useful because it explains the concepts of reactive programming and key features.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I did what you suggested, but things are still not working. I know that the Store state is also an Observable, but how do tell the @ngrx to use my mock state? I tried to change my import line to this: `StoreModule.forRoot({ orders: ordersReducer, config: { initialState: storeSpy } })`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I provide the store in my tests this way: 
`TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: Store, useValue: storeSpy }
      ]
    })`

Comment: Hi, I tried to provide the store the way you did, but it didn't work. I got this error: `TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Comment: I continued my tests and I provided an `Observable` instead of a `spyobj` and everything worked fine: `const storeSpy = Observable.of(ordersStateMock);`. However I think that this solution will not work if I try to call the `store.dispatch` method, for example.

Comment: Calling the dispatch method should not be in the scope of this test as you are unit testing the effects, not the mechanism of the store.

Comment: Yes, this was what thought as well. Thanks for the great help!

Comment: PS: I've been looking into the documentation and I stumbled another way of mocking the initial state: `imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({ orders: ordersReducer }, { initialState: ordersStateMock })
      ],`.

Comment: Is this still working for ngrx 5.2.0? I suppose when you provide a storeSpy, you don't need to do StoreModule.forRoot right? For me, it's complaning effects.loadAllOrders$ is not an observable...

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking at the @ngrx documentation and I found another possible answer to mocking the store state (see the complete code below):

```
let actions;
let effects: OrderEffect;
let ordersStateMock;

beforeEach(() => {

  ordersStateMock = {
    orders: {
      pollingInterval: 30
    }
  };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      StoreModule.forRoot(
        { orders: ordersReducer },
        { initialState: ordersStateMock }
      )
    ],
    providers: [
      OrderEffect,
      provideMockActions(() => actions),
      { provide: OrderService,
        useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('orderService', ['getAllOrders'])
      }
    ]
  });

  effects = TestBed.get(OrderEffect);
});
```

Apparently I just needed to set the initial state in the `StoreModule` import.

Comment: initialState doesn't seem to work when using ngrx/entities

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solutions don't work for me.  I am using ngrx 5.2.0 (with ngrx entity) and Angular 5.2.9.  The metaReducer idea works as documented here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/414#issuecomment-331354701

In my case, I want to mock some state.  So my metaReducer looks like:

```
  export function mockMetaReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any, any> {
    return function(state: any, action: any): any {
      return reducer(ordersStateMock, action);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/414#issuecomment-393540332) is the simplest and worked for me with **ngrx: 5.2.0**

Create mock for Store that based on real Store

```
export class StoreMock<T = any> extends Store<T> {

    public source = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

    public overrideState(allStates: any) {
        this.source.next(allStates);
    }

}
```

And use it in tests

```
let store: StoreMock<YourStateModel>;

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: Store, useClass: StoreMock },
    ]
});
store = TestBed.get(Store);


beforeEach(() => {
    store.overrideState({
        currentStateName: MOCKED_STATE_DATA_OBJECT
    });
});
```